# Pydantic, Django Ninja "Day is out of range for month"

Tags: django, validation, pydantic, django-ninja

2024-02-29 14:04:15 pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for NinjaResponseSchema
2024-02-29 14:04:15 response
2024-02-29 14:04:15   day is out of range for month (type=value_error)

I have fields "created_at" and "updated_at". Today my project crashed because of them. How can I update validators in schemas to skip those fields validation?

I've tried multiple things but nothing helped me. My versions:

django-ninja==0.22.0
pydantic==1.10.14

Comment: What value you are trying to pass as date? Usually this error is raised when you try to pass invalid date. For example 30 February

Answer (score 0):

Use Pydantic's conditional validation to selectively validate fields based on a condition:

```
from pydantic import validator

class MyResponseSchema(Schema):
    created_at: datetime = Field(...)
    updated_at: datetime = Field(...)

    @validator('created_at', 'updated_at', pre=True, always=True)
    def skip_validation_for_specific_dates(cls, v):
        if v == "2024-02-29":  
            return v 
        return parse_datetime(v)
```

**but before you have to install pydantic with this :**

> pip install pydantic